# Compilation Error: CS1061

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I understand there are few answers quite similar on this site but I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong here. Full error message are here:

Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.webform1_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'addNumbers' and no extension method 'addNumbers' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.webform1_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Line 37:             
Line 38:

> Line 39:

Line 40:         
Line 41:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script>
            function addNumbers()
            {
                var firstNumber = parseFloat(document.getElementById("TextBox1").value);
                var secondNumber = parseFloat(document.getElementById("TextBox2").value);
                document.getElementById("TextBox3").value = firstNumber + secondNumber; 
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>First Number: </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Second Number: </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Result: </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="addNumbers()" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Code from as aspx.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;



    namespace WebApplication2
    {
        public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="addNumbers()" />
```

requires your to have `OnClick` method in code-behind file. I think that you need normal, not server-side button:

```
<button onclick="addNumbers()">Add</button>
```

Comment: You can mark my answer as a solution to your question, so other people coming to stackoverflow will benefit.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) - The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted".

Comment: I think I did that, very new to programming and stackoverflow.